# Writing a C# DateTime using HDF5.NET that can be read by PyTables

Tags: c#, .net, hdf5, pytables

I'm writing a data logging application in C# using HDF5.NET. The .h5 files that are written will then be opened and analysed using PyTables.

PyTables uses `Time32Col` and `Time64Col` to store timestamps in HDF5 files. For files created with PyTables, this works great.

I know HDF5 stores timestamps as 4 or 8-byte UNIX timestamps (https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.6/UG/12_Datatypes.html) and I'm able to use C# to convert the .NET `DateTime` to unix timestamps no trouble, but the problem is in creating the H5 Type so that when I open the file on the other end PyTables knows it's a timestamp.

The documentation says to use one of `H5T_UNIX_D32LE`, `H5T_UNIX_D32LE`, `H5T_UNIX_D32LE` or `H5T_UNIX_D32LE`. The problem is that none of these are available in the `H5T.H5Type` of HDF5.NET.

Does anyone have a workaround?